# How can I make Visual Studio learn of new environment variables without having to restart my system

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, environment-variables

I've seen posts asking about how to get environment variables to be refreshed without having to close VStudio, but for me, I just want to know how I can make the changes without having to restart my system. I really don't understand how it can't detect the new changes - I've totally made sure the process is not hanging around and even used the vcvars32.bat to pick up new changes before re-opening. I can't find a solution. My environment variables can be used from elsewhere (ie. %variablename% works in cmd.exe). Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The environment that is being used is the one from windows explorer.  You would have to restart explorer for the changes to appear.

There is a way to apply the changes to the current environment. You might want to try SuperUser.com

Comment: thank you~ restarting explorer works, ugly but fine for my needs.

Comment: Ugly to say the least - kind of like using your home's fuse box to turn your computer on and off.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/107521/why-are-changes-to-my-path-not-being-recognised for a possible reason for the updated environment not being recognized everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Since the new environment variable is visible in the cmd window, why not start VS from there? The `devenv` command will start the VS IDE. You can tell it to load a particular solution or project.

```
devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext]  [switches]
```

The VS IDE will pick up the environment variable state that's in effect in that cmd window.  However, note that certain environment variables will *not* be picked up unless you use the `/useenv` option:

- `/useenv`: Use PATH, INCLUDE, LIBPATH, and LIB environment variables instead of IDE paths for VC++ builds.

Also note that it also accepts a bunch of options (mainly to build projects from the command line); use `devenv /?` to get details.